# Как сделать, чтобы фоновое видео заканчивалось вместе с наложеным видео

Tags: ffmpeg

есть код для ffmppeg, с помощью него я могу поверх фонового видео 1.mp4 наложить другое видео с нужным мне размером, но проблема в том, что наложенное видео заканчивается, а фоновое длится дальше.

как сделать что бы наложеное видео закончилось и фоновое тоже?

вот такой код у меня:

```
$ ffmpeg -i "!background_video!" -i "!input_video!" \
-filter_complex "[1]scale=-1:800[vid]; [0]scale=576:1024[1.mp4]; [1.mp4] [vid] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2 " \
-map 1:a -y "!output_video!"
```